# Why does git branch -t fail with "Not tracking: ambiguous information"?

Tags: git, branch

When I try to create a new branch tracking a remote branch, I get this:

```
$ git branch -t test origin/foo
error: Not tracking: ambiguous information for ref refs/remotes/origin/foo
```

[The source](http://github.com/git/git/blob/5ad9dce7e691106fecde413de8cc321b937367a6/branch.c) seems to somehow search for branches to track and throws me out because it finds <del>less</del> more than one, but I don't exactly get what it's looking for since I already told it what to track on the command line.

Can anybody tell me what's going on and how to fix it?

Comment: Just added some terminology, and some suggestions (just leads to explore, nothing definitive though) to explain the current situation.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, but did you actually found the reason behind your error message?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Got it! The problem was that I have previously set up a remote with `--mirror`, for the purpose of having a backup / public copy of my repository.

If you run

```
git remote add --mirror <name> <url>
```

it does not only flag the remote as mirror (which is what I wanted for pushes), but also configures `remote.<mirror>.fetch` option for the mirror to `+refs/*:refs/*`, which means that all of your branches suddenly "track" your mirror repository and any attempt to create a tracking branch is going to fail.

(As an added bonus, running `git fetch <mirror>` is going to overwrite all your refs with old ones from your backup repo.)

The solution that seems to fix this issue is setting `remote.<mirror>.fetch` to `:` (which, I hope, means "never fetch anything"). This apparently fixes the tracking issue and eliminates the deadly fetch.

Comment: I had exactly this problem, and this solution fixed it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 44):

I saw this also when I had two remote repo's with the same (default) fetch pattern (`fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`) and the same branches.

The original mistake was in creating two remotes with the same `fetch` configuration. The new remote has a different name, and therefore the name of its folder should have been changed as well. Here is an example of a proper multiple-remote configuration:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = <primary-source>
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[remote "alt"]
    url = <alternate-source>
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/alt/*
```

In place of `alt` put any name of your choosing.

**Explanation:**

The meaning of `refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` is: take all the remote reference in `refs/heads` on the remote side, and put the to `refs/heads/origin` on our side. `refs/heads` is the path where branches are stored, so if you have branch `foo` on the remote, it will be fetched to `origin/foo` in your local repo. The `+` on the beginning means that the destination branches should be always overwritten (w/o that there are some additional checks).

**Alternatively:**

You can also manually add the info to the project's `.git/config`, e.g.:

```
[branch "mybranch"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/mybranch
```

Comment: I guess the fix would be to have different remotes fetch to different places, eg. instead of both having `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`, try to rename the second destination to something like `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/another_repo/*`.

Comment: A very good point -- the reference to origin in the second repo doesn't seem right.

I really need to go away and fully understand what the "fetch" lines really mean, so I can configure the second repo (which is essentially a mirror) properly.

Comment: The meaning of `refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` is: take all the remote reference in `refs/heads` on the remote side, and put the to `refs/heads/origin` on our side. `refs/heads` is the path where branches are stored, so if you have branch `foo` on the remote, it will be fetched to `origin/foo` in your local repo. The `+` on the beginning means that the destination branches should be always overwritten (w/o that there are some additional checks).

Comment: Thanks for that, that really helps. I was totally misreading what that meant.

Comment: @che This really helped me. Having two remotes with the same place to put tags overwrote those every time because of this. Maybe you should make your own answer :)

Comment: @Sylwester: I can't make an answer if I don't know the question :-) You can help others by writing up your problem as a question and then answering it yourself with the information you just found.

Comment: @MatthewPhillips Thank you!  I was having this problem and this explained it.  After getting rid of the second remote (now unused, anyway) I am able to  assign upstreams normally again.

Answer (score 17):

> because it finds less than one

Nope: because it finds *more* than one matching remote branch, which means the function `remote_find_tracking()` returns more than one tracking branch for a given local branch ref.

Is `some_remote_branch` not *already* tracked by one of your local branches?
(a `git config -l` would allow you to check what you have currently have set up).
(a `git branch -r` can also help to list your current remote-tracking branches. )

See also "[copy a branch from one to another repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71961151/6309)" for more details with Git 2.36 (Q2 2022).

---

> remote branches, which I thought are something different that remote-tracking branches.

Wrong, as illustrated by [this thread](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2007/8/4/253967):

> remote-branches are the "real" remote-tracking-branches. You don't commit to them locally, they are essentially read-only copies of exactly what is happening in a remote repository.
> If you try to   'git-checkout' a remote-tracking branch, you will get a detached HEAD.
>
> Local branch:
> A branch to which you may commit changes. Optionally, the branch can be   configured to "follow" one of your remote-tracking branches. This means that a '`git-pull`' without arguments (when your local branch is checked out), will automatically '`git-fetch`' and then '`git-merge`' the remote-tracking branch.

Now:

> it's the job of `git-fetch` to update remote-tracking branches with any changes found in the remote repository.
> `Git-pull` runs `git-fetch` and then runs a `git-merge` to update the currently-checked-out branch.

The problem is, for git-merge:

> When this happens, `git-merge` must decide which `remote-tracking-branch` to merge into the currently checked out local branch.
> You can set which `remote-tracking-branch` will be selected in this situation with the --track option.
>
> `--track` sets up a local following branch to refer to a remote's branch, *not* to the tracking branch

[Consider that](http://github.com/git/git/blob/79b4fde573eb5e86a8109d100ad182be1eb5fc54/remote.c) `remote_find_tracking()` takes a single remote and a refspec with src filled, and returns the given refspec after filling its dst, if an appropriate tracking was configured for the remote, meaning git.

```
/*
 * For the given remote, reads the refspec's src and sets the other fields.
 */
int remote_find_tracking(struct remote *remote, struct refspec *refspec);
```

May be it considers it already has a local following branch matching `some_remote_branch`. Do you have any local branch with that exact same name?
Or, the other way around: your current branch has a remote branch with a similar name, which makes it a natural candidate for any `git-merge`: trying to make it track *another* remote branch would make the `git-merge` unable to choose which local branch to update/merge with changes of a remote.

Comment: I managed to write exactly the opposite of "more", thanks for pointing that out :-)

Anyway, I seem to get the message even if I try to set up local branch from a remote branch that I just got by git-fetch. git config -l does not contain anything familiar to the remote branch, and git branch -r just lists remote branches, which I thought are something different that remote-tracking branches. Or am I confusing stuff?

Comment: Thanks for detailed reply, as I'm reading it I guess the main problem was that I didn't quite know what I was doing.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It helped me figure out that my problem was caused by having 2 remotes with the same fetch pattern.

Answer (score 5):

None of the other fixes mentioned here worked for me. The one that ended up working was this:

```
$ git branch -t test origin/test
error: Not tracking: ambiguous information for ref refs/remotes/origin/test
```

After running the above, even though git complained, it did end up creating a local branch `test` but no upstream set.

Now, I opened the `.git/config` file (which did not have any record of a branch `test`) and added the following manually:

```
[branch "test"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/test
```

After which everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I got in a situation like this, but I do not know how. The listing from `git branch -av` showed me only a single remote tracking branch for the branch I cared about (`origin/dev`).

What I did to fix it was to use the hexadecimal commit hash instead of `origin/dev`:

```
git checkout -b dev abc123
git push -u origin dev
```

When I did the push with `-u` Git said `Branch dev set up to track remote branch dev from origin.` Subsequent pulls and pushes worked as I expected.